# sudo command inside heredoc block in a ssh session is not working

Tags: terminal, sshd

When i use heredoc and put all the commands inside heredoc as,

```
ssh -t -i master.pem cloud-user@$1 <<EOSSH
sudo service x restart
sudo service y restart
EOSSH
```

it throws error as,

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

When i add another -t option, it works good,

```
ssh -t -t -i master.pem cloud-user@$1 <<EOSSH
sudo service x restart
sudo service y restart
EOSSH
```

What does `pseudo-terminal` mean, in the context of a ssh session?

`stdin is not a terminal` - Doesn't bash provide a stdin terminal to the ssh client?

What does `-t` option mean and how is `-t -t` different from `-t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in `man ssh`:

> -t              Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi‐
>           
>            trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
>           
>            very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  **Multiple -t
>           
>            options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.**

Comment: hi terdon, ssh server reads the stream of input via a socket and runs them  as commands. It just need a tcp/ip socket. when and why does the ssh server need a terminal?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar oh, it's sudo that needs it to get the password

Comment: It may _not_ need a terminal. Ssh is printing the pseudo-tty notice because it was run with "-t". It has no idea whether the commands run on the remote server need a tty or not.